# xceed avalonDock FloatingWindows it must be dockable on more DockingManager

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, avalondock, xceed

"I have two or more dockingManager, and I want every FloatingWindows to be dockable on every dockingManager."

floatingWindows must be created within a dockingManager, but it must be possible to dock it into another separate docking manager.
so when I do drag inside the first dockingManager the default positions are displayed. (4 icons: top, left, bottom, right)
but when I drag the floatingWindows into the second dockingManager nothing appears.

```
<Grid>
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dock1" Width="300" Height="200">
    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
            <avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow>
                <avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockHeight="100" DockWidth="100">
                    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorablePane x:Name="_LayoutAnchorablePane" FloatingHeight="150" FloatingWidth="150">
                        <avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorableTitle="FloatingWindow">
                            <Grid Background="CornflowerBlue">

                            </Grid>
                        </avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
            </avalonDockLayout:LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindow>
        </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot.FloatingWindows>
    </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>

<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dock2" Width="300" Height="200" >
    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>

    </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager/>
```

I also tried to force it from code, but it does not work!

```
    LayoutAnchorable mAnchorableChilder=null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        mAnchorableChilder = new LayoutAnchorable();
        mAnchorableChilder.Title = "Sample dynamic avalondock";
        _LayoutAnchorablePane.Children.Add(mAnchorableChilder);
        Grid grid = new Grid { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) };

        mAnchorableChilder.Content = grid;
    }
```

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds strange to me from a design perspective, but from reading the [documentation](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock) it also sounds like it may not be possible _"There is only one logical tree, which has the DockingManager as its root. Even if a control is placed in a different window (i.e., an autohidden window or a floating window), it always belong to the same logical tree below the DockingManager."_

Comment: This is actually not possible. AvalonDock actually supports only one DockingManager at a time - this restriction is build in since others tried to out a DockingManager  insisde a document and generated thus, a bunch of hard to solve problems.

So, the only way to solve this request would be to:
1. Path the DragService class such that drag & drop to other DockingManager's is possible

2. Catch the Drop event at the target and re-create the document in the target DockumentManager, which is a very difficult thing to do, and requires a lot of effort and inside knowledge ...